# After pushing to CF git is not updated

Tags: git, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

I am using Bluemix services on CloudFoundry, I cloned the app locally and when I do `cf push` I get really weird behavior: I see my changes on the actual app, but I don't see them in the repository!

If I pull from another device, or use the online editor, the changes I pushed do not appear. I commit them as I would with git `git commit -am "bla"` and then do `cf push`, and git pull on another device.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have your git repository containing your source code and you have your running application on Bluemix.

When you run `cf push` you deploy a new version of the application from your local environment to Bluemix. Using `git push` after a `git commit` you push the changes to the git repository. Please double check that you run `git push` to update the code on the repository.

If you are using the Web IDE in IBM DevOps Services please make sure that you click on *Commit* and then *Push*.